# How to make Custom Gate for Bottom staircase

Tags: stairs, gates

The staircase in my house is quite steep. It originally had no railings with dropoffs as high as 8ft on each side.There is a room on one side of staircase and a hallway on the otherside of it. At the bottom of the stairs there is a 3ft width landing that ends with a wall. The staircase is 50in wide. there is one metal railing going down the side that has the room. The railing is made up of wrought metal rods that go into ceiling. So theres no wall in between the rods. I need help figuring out how to make a custom gate that can go on first step (so it doesnt block entrance to the room or hallway) and a type of barrier up the sides of staircase.The over all goal of our project is to prevent our toddler gaining access to the staircase.

[image]jpg

Comment: A gate should be easy.  You will need to add a wall/proper railing on the hallway side to make a gate useful.  Might be a toddler now, but they have a bad habit of growing and climbing higher.  The size(between the rails) of the red railing is what you need all the way up the stairs.

Comment: Also note the spacing between balusters (if you go with that design) should not exceed 4".